# If a <td> contains "a" then make the <tr> background red but the each() is to slow

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you write this so it runs faster. It looks like because I'm using an each() it is slowing it down.

Can I use filter()?

```
 $("#X tr").each(function () {       
     if ($(this).find("table td:eq(1)").text() == "a") {
         $(this).css("background":"red");    
  }

});   

     <table id = "X">
        <tr >
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        ...
        <tr >
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `:contains` selector: http://jsfiddle.net/Af6Nz/1/.

```
​$("#X tr:contains('a')").css("background-color", "red");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: `:contains` checks text, it does not take a selector as an argument.

Comment: @jackwanders: The OP's example is about the text `a`, not `<a>` elements if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest:

```
$('td:contains("a")').closest('tr').css('background-color','red');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bQ3EC/).

Or, in to affect *all* ancestor `tr` elements:

```
$('td:contains("a")').parents('tr').css('background-color','red');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bQ3EC/1/).

Or to affect all `tr` elements with descendent (however deeply nested):

```
$('tr').filter(
    function(){
        return $(this).find('td:contains("a")').length;
    }).css('background-color','red');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bQ3EC/2/).

Added a function, `lookAt()` that might be used instead:

```
function lookAt(haystack, needle) {
    if (!haystack) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        needle = needle ? needle : 'a';
        for (var i = 0, len = haystack.childNodes.length; i < len; i++) {
            var cur = haystack.childNodes[i];
            if (cur.nodeType == 3 && cur.nodeValue.indexOf(needle) > -1){
                return true;
            }
            else if (i == (len-1)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

$('#table td').filter(
    function() {
        return lookAt(this);
    }).css('background-color', 'red');​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bQ3EC/3/)

[JS Perf test examining the `lookAt()` function approach against the `return $(this).is(':contains("a")')` Sizzle-based approach](http://jsperf.com/contains-versus-a-homemade-function).

For reference, for a closer comparison the JS Perf jQuery test was the following:

```
$('#table td').filter(
    function() {
        return $(this).is(':contains("a")')
    }).css('background-color', 'red');​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bQ3EC/4/).

Comment: keep in mind that this will not work if `a` is not a direct child of `td` , for example if `a` is in a `span` in a `td`.

Comment: I think OP wants to match cells containing the text `a`, not a `<a>` tag

Comment: this will style `<td>` tags; OP asked to style `<tr>` tags

Comment: ...for goodness' sake. I'm *sure* I can remember learning to read at one point, not something I thought I'd forget how to do so easily. Or suddenly. *Sigh*

Comment: @DavidThomas: In the *child-selector* docs, jQuery advises against selectors that start with `>`. Also, if speed is the objective, it's best to avoid custom Sizzle selectors, like `:contains`.

Answer (score 3):

Using [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and `parent` (to go back to the `tr` that we want to colorize) :

```
$(this).find('td:eq(0):contains("a")').parent().css("background","red");
```

or using [has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) :

```
$(this).find('tr:has(td:eq(0):contains("a"))').css("background","red");
```

If you don't need the `eq` condition, use

```
$(this).find('td:contains("a")').parent().css("background","red");
```

Keep in mind that [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) is 0-based (as your test case didn't involve a matching element with 1 instead of 0).

Demonstration : http://jsfiddle.net/KRqQN/

Comment: you could even omit `table`, since it's not likely that the `td` is outside of a table ;)

Comment: great thanks - what if I only want to check the first cell of the row?

Comment: Note that `contains("a")` would also match elements with an `a` anywhere in its text, e.g. `<td>cat</td>`

Comment: Note that the first cell is `eq(0)`, not `eq(1)`.

Comment: @arnaud576875 yes. I remove it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about performance, the following might help.

```
var getText = (function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');

  if (typeof div.textContent == 'string') {
    return function (el) {
      return el.textContent;
    };

  } else if (typeof div.innerText == 'string') {
    return function (el) {
      return el.innerText;
    };
  }
}());

function foo(table) {
  var row, rows = table.rows;
  var i = rows.length;
  var re = /a/;

  while (i--) {
    row = rows[i];

    if (re.test(getText(row))) {
      row.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was sort of heading, very incrementally, in this direction. May I commend you, and +1, on the [*fantastic* performance of your functions](http://jsperf.com/contains-versus-a-homemade-function/edit). =)